# How to Get the Menu Closed By Default in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a website in Jquery and HTMl and i have a side Navigation Menus.
But By default i am getting the menu open i want that menu to get open when i click on that.

```
$("div#mws-navigation ul li a, div#mws-navigation ul li span")
            .bind('click', function (event) {
                if ($(this).next('ul').size() !== 0) {
                    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('fast', function () {
                        $(this).toggleClass('closed');
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

This is the code. when i click on menu I get the menu open and closed. But by default i want that menu Open.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of it, that would be easier to solve. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This is because your UL's do not currently have a .closed class and as a result they are not being set to `display: none`. What you should be doing is in CSS hiding them and then adding a class to show them. That said, you would need a fallback if javascript is disabled.

Comment: @gavin Yes correct.. I added class closed to UL and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @Gavin Maybe you can submit your comment as an answer so Moiz can accept an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do the following:

```
 $().(function (){
     var closeMe = $("div#mws-navigation ul li a ul, div#mws-navigation ul li span ul");
     closeMe.size(0);
     closeMe.toggleClass('closed');
 });
```

Comment: @MoizKachwala It's more of a concept, I don't know how your HTML looks like. Update your question with it or create a jsfiddle for it. I'll gladly take another look then.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i got my solution. i added class closed to UL and my issue got solved.

Comment: No problem, thought something like that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working correctly,try this:

```
$("div#mws-navigation ul li a, div#mws-navigation ul li span")
            .bind('click', function (event) {
                if ($(this).next('ul').size() !== 0) {
                    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('fast', function () {
                        $(this).toggleClass('closed');
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }).addClass('closed');
```